# Debian Wheezy in KVM: can't set IO scheduler

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, debian-wheezy

I'm running a Wheezy box in KVM, by default it runs the kernel 3.2. After I upgrade to 3.14 from backports, I no longer can tune the IO scheduler.

Before:

```
# cat /sys/block/vda/queue/scheduler
noop deadline [cfq]

# echo noop > /sys/block/vda/queue/scheduler
# cat /sys/block/vda/queue/scheduler
[noop] deadline cfq
```

After:

```
# cat /sys/block/vda/queue/scheduler
none

# echo noop > /sys/block/vda/queue/scheduler
# cat /sys/block/vda/queue/scheduler
none
```

The host and VM configuration are untouched.
What could be the problem?

Comment: do you have any error in your messagges when you try to change the io scheduler?

Comment: @c4f4t0r no, nothing at all.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use anything other than none.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel you updated to likely does not have scheduler support you are looking for

e.g. you should be seeing something like this

```
egrep 'CONFIG_IOSCHED_.*=y' /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_IOSCHED_NOOP=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_DEADLINE=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ=y
```

Where did you get that 3.14 kernel? If you were building it make sure you have those config options set for your build.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a feature rather than a bug.  I am seeing the same on CentOS v7.1
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1305843

Comment: great answer ... a link to an board, where you should be a subscriber ...